# How to stop next podcast always auto-playing when current one finishes in iOS?

Tags: ios, podcasts.app

How do I permanently disable the Podcast app auto playing the next unplayed podcast episode when the current one finishes? It even plays episodes of other podcasts, not just the podcast I was listening to.

The only way I'm aware of is to set the sleep timer to "When Current Episode Ends", but this only applies to the currently playing podcast. I'd have to remember to set this option every single time I start a podcast playing which I don't want to have to do.

I'm using an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.2 and Podcasts version 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings - podcast - turn off continuous playback. Link below with photos.

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/01/18/how-to-disable-automatic-playback-apple-podcasts-app/

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/podcasts_ios.html